# elastic beanstalk ec2 eb ssh suddenly timeout error from yesterday

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

Ouput INFO: Attempting to open port 22.
INFO: SSH port 22 open.
ssh: connect to host xx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22: Operation timed out 
INFO: Closed port 22 on ec2 instance security group.
ERROR: An error occurred while running ssh.

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty informative. It says that port 22 is closed on the security group(s) attached to the instance, most likely because you modified the rules on the security group(s) or because you had access configured based on your workstation IP address and that IP address changed.

Check the rules regarding SSH (TCP port 22) on the security groups of your instance (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html) and also check the rules on the network ACLs (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_ACLs.html) of the subnet the ENI attached to the instance belongs to (if running the instance in a VPC).

Comment: Thanks, but i think port is opened because of ssh error (after timeout) port closed. Can you check on your side and confirm it if you are also managing ec2 instance. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

figured out that my ISP (BSNL India) has blocked port 22 access to servers, hence the issue. tested that I'm able to ssh using a different ISP.
oh! and, I'd terminated my t2 xlarge with the ip 54.148.232.69. so when you managed to ssh, it was probably with someone else. Thanks for the help :slight_smile:
Any idea if we could ssh using a different port? if port 22 is the only way to go, I might have to consider switching my ISP and the process takes at least more than a week I believe.

Answer (score -1):

Worked after switching to mobile hotspot network.
but don't know the reason. But still not working on the other connection.